# javafx aplication start on raspberry Pi

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi

Hi I want to start my java application on raspberry I export DISPLAY:=0.0
 and next I start a program like this : /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -jar Main.jar

and I see this :

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image dimensions must be positive (w,h > 0)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:720)
        at javafx.scene.image.WritableImage.<init>(WritableImage.java:74)
        at application.Main4.makeTransparent(Main4.java:436)
        at application.Main4.start(Main4.java:129)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication$RunnableEvent.dispatch(LensApplication.java:182)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication._runLoop(LensApplication.java:860)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication.access$1800(LensApplication.java:58)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication$4.run(LensApplication.java:917)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main4
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to say. But, it looks like you might have a typo. Exception running application application.**Main4**  Should that be just Main?